# How to Render a rails view without the application data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

What I am trying to do is perform an AJAX request from within a mobile app. I want to render a rails view without the application template data such as the  tags etc.

This way I can only get the data I need.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
render :layout => false
```

This will render the view template without the application template.  Lots more on rendering here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Perfect that's exactly it. Thanks.